# How do I read app.config appSettings use with DI in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, caliburn.micro

I'm building a WPF app and I'm using Caliburn.Micro, I have a project within the solution for the DataHandling and I want to pass the ConnectionString from the appSettings to the DataHandling class using DI.

I've set up a SimpleContainer in the Bootstrapper class and configured to register a PerRequest for the class.

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    _container.Instance(_container);

    _container
    .Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>()
    .Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

    _container
        .PerRequest<IDataHandler, DataHandler>();
```

In the class I'd like to inject the SqlConnectionString using something like this

```
public class DataHandler : IDataHandler
{
   private SqlOptions _sqlOptions;
   public DataHandler(IOptions<SqlOptions> sqlOptions)
   {
       _sqlOptions = sqlOptions.Value;
   }
```

The model for SqlOptions looks like this

```
public class SqlOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

My question is do I read the values from appSettings as part of the Bootstrapper (or should that be done in the Viewmodel for the startup view) and how should I put them into the container for use in the DataHandler.

Any help or pointers to documentation would be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works. I hadn't realised that the ConfigurationManager is available to the DataHandler project (presumably from the Host that is used in Caliburn.Micro). So my code now looks like this

```
    private string _sqlConnectionString;
    public DataHandler()
    {
        _sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SqlConnectionString");
    }
```

If anyone can see any issues with this solution it woul dbe good to read your comments.
Thanks.